# Resizing a HTML canvas blanks its contents

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a HTML canvas element which is resized when the user resizes the screen.

```
canvas.height = pageHeight();
canvas.width = pageWidth();
```

The actual resizing works fine, but it blanks the canvas.

I would like to keep the contents. Is there another method of changing the size of a canvas element, or is there a way to store the contents and then draw them back to the canvas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to either resize the canvas with CSS or redraw the canvas after you resize it.

If you want to save the content of the canvas and redraw it, I can think of a few options:

1. Use `context.getImageData` to grab the whole canvas, resize the canvas, then use `context.putImageData` to redraw it at the new scale.
2. Create an `Image` object, setting the source to the result of `canvas.toDataUrl()`, resize the canvas, then draw the image at the new scale.
3. call `context.setScale(xscale, yscale)` and call whatever function you used to draw the canvas originally. Assuming you set up `xscale` and `yscale` correctly, it will automatically scale everything to the new size.
4. Create a new canvas with the updated size and call `context.drawImage(oldCanvas, ...)` to copy the old canvas onto the new one. Then you would switch out the old canvas with the new one.

The first two options won't work if you have drawn an image from a different domain to the canvas at any time, and aren't supported by older implementations.

In my opinion, option 3 (redrawing the image at the new scale) is the best if it's possible. It's the only option that will keep your lines completely smooth and sharp, and it will always work (assuming you still have all the information to generate the image).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatly I can't redraw the original data as it's user generated. So I went for option 1.

Comment: Slight correction to your point 1. It's putImageData, not setImageData.

Comment: I used:
var imgD = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width - 1, canvas.height - 1);
ctx.putImageData(imgD, 0, 0);

Comment: Without the -1 for width and height you get the error: An invalid or illegal string was specified" code: "12

Comment: @Richard: Thanks for the correction. The "invalid or illegal string..." error seems like a bug, but whatever works I guess.

Comment: you could save the canvas content aways the user change it... then you can use this temp content after resize