# Preventing Canvas Clear when Resizing Window

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, resize

I'm trying to create a simple app that draws rectangles within the Canvas tag. I've got the Canvas resizing to fullscreen, but whenever I resize the viewport, Canvas clears. I'm trying to prevent it from clearing and just keeping the content that's within it. Any ideas?

http://mediajux.com/experiments/canvas/drawing/

```
  /*
  * This is the primary class used for the application
  * @author Alvin Crespo
  */
  var app = (function(){

    var domBod          = document.body;
    var canvas          = null;
    var canvasWidth     = null;
    var canvasHeight     = null;
  
    return {

      //Runs after the DOM has achieved an onreadystatechange of "complete"
      initApplication: function()
      {
        //setup envrionment variables
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas') || null;
  
        //we need to resize the canvas at the start of the app to be the full window
        this.windowResized();
  
        //only set the canvas height and width if it is not false/null
        if(canvas)
        {
          canvasWidth = canvas.offsetWidth;
          canvasHeight = canvas.offsetHeight;        
        }
  
        //add window events
        window.onresize = this.windowResized;   
  
        circles.canvas = canvas;
        circles.canvasWidth = canvasWidth;
        circles.canvasHeight = canvasHeight;
        circles.generateCircles(10);  
  
        setInterval(function(){
            circles.animateCircles();
        }, 50);   
      },

      /**
      * Executes Resizing procedures on the canvas element
      */
      windowResized: function()
      {
        (this.domBod === null) ? 'true' : 'false';
        try{
          console.log(canvas);
          canvas.setAttribute('width', document.body.clientWidth);
          canvas.setAttribute('height', document.body.clientHeight);        
        }catch(e) {
          console.log(e.name + " :: " + e.message);
        }
      },

      /**
      * Returns the canvas element 
      * @returns canvas
      */
      getCanvas: function()
      {
        return canvas;
      }

    };
  })();
```

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23128583/1265753

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have implement a listener for screen resize and redraw the canvas content when that listener fires.

Comment: Yeah, I actually do. window.onresize = this.windowResized I've added some of the code above.

Comment: I see that you are resizing the canvas, but you are not performing any draw operations after the canvas is resized. Add a function that does your drawing and call it after the calls to change the height and width attribute.

Answer (score 25):

*Setting the canvas width attribute will clear the canvas.*
If you resize the style width (e.g. `canvas.style.visibility`), it will scale (usually not in such a pretty way).
If you want to make the canvas bigger but keep the elements in it as they are, I would suggest storing the canvas as an image -- e.g. call the `toDataURL` method to get the image, then draw that to the resized canvas with `drawImage()`.

Comment: e.g. `canvas.style.width = "320px";`

Comment: Unbelievably I didn't know changing the height or width attribute will clear the canvas!

Comment: Why bother with `toDataURL` when you can [simply use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70124883/765294) `getImageData()`/`putImageData()`?

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I solved this problem with [JS3](http://js3.quietless.com).

Internally, I store the main canvas and context as _canvas and _context respectively.

```
function resize(w, h){
// create a temporary canvas obj to cache the pixel data //
    var temp_cnvs = document.createElement('canvas');
    var temp_cntx = temp_cnvs.getContext('2d');
// set it to the new width & height and draw the current canvas data into it // 
    temp_cnvs.width = w; 
    temp_cnvs.height = h;
    temp_cntx.fillStyle = _background;  // the original canvas's background color
    temp_cntx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    temp_cntx.drawImage(_canvas, 0, 0);
// resize & clear the original canvas and copy back in the cached pixel data //
    _canvas.width = w; 
    _canvas.height = h;
    _context.drawImage(temp_cnvs, 0, 0);
}
```

[JS3](http://js3.quietless.com) also provides an [autoSize](http://js3.quietless.com/api) flag which will automatically resize your canvas to the browser window or the dimensions of its parent div.

Answer (score 7):

one way I solved this was:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('ctx')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var W = canvas.width, H = canvas.height
function resize() {
    let temp = ctx.getImageData(0,0,W,H)
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 99;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 99;
    W = canvas.width, H = canvas.height
    ctx.putImageData(temp,0,0)
}
```

the only issue is that on zooming back out you lose the data that was outside the canvas

Answer (score 4):

Set canvas size with style (css) and do not change attributes.

After resize to fullscreen

Canvas will be resized and not cleared, but will be scaled, than to prevent scale - you need rescale after resize, here is math:

```
var oldWidth    =  $("canvas").css("width").replace("px", "");
var oldHeight   = $("canvas").css("height").replace("px", "");  

$("canvas").css({ 
            "width" : window.innerWidth, 
            "height": window.innerHeight
        }); 



var ratio1 =  oldWidth/window.innerWidth;
var ratio2 =  oldHeight/window.innerHeight;



canvas.ctx.scale(ratio1, ratio2);
```

Please note, that I made copy paste from my code and do some changes with ids and vars names for fast, so could have some small mistkaes like "canvas.ctx" or dom calls.

Comment: This won't work for me.  When I use css in Chrome to set the canvas size, it draws distorted! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage#The_<canvas>_element

Comment: Works great. Cheers!

Comment: As Evildonald mentioned, this approach isn't recommended if you want to do any kind of drawing on the canvas. Here's a fiddle demonstrating how adjusting dimensions via CSS produces undesirable drawing behaviour: https://jsfiddle.net/kuLLe2wo/

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue with my canvas and I have resolved that issue. Please refer the below code. I hope you will resolved the issue using this.

**Note** : Set `alwaysDraw: true` in the parameters

**HTML**

```
<div id="top-wraper">
        <div id="canvas"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- div used to create our plane -->
    <div class="plane" data-vs-id="plane-vs" data-fs-id="plane-fs">
        <!-- image that will be used as a texture by our plane -->
        <img src="texture-img.png" alt="Leo Music - Music from the heart of a Lion"/>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>

    function loadAnimation() {
        // set up our WebGL context and append the canvas to our wrapper
        var webGLCurtain = new Curtains("canvas");
        webGLCurtain.width = 50;
        // if there's any error during init, we're going to catch it here
        webGLCurtain.onError(function () {
            // we will add a class to the document body to display original images
            document.body.classList.add("no-curtains");
        });
        // get our plane element
        var planeElement = document.getElementsByClassName("plane")[0];
        // set our initial parameters (basic uniforms)
        var params = {
            vertexShaderID: "plane-vs", // our vertex shader ID
            fragmentShaderID: "plane-fs", // our framgent shader ID
            alwaysDraw: true,
            //crossOrigin: "", // codepen specific
            uniforms: {
                time: {
                    name: "uTime", // uniform name that will be passed to our shaders
                    type: "1f", // this means our uniform is a float
                    value: 0,
                },
            }
        }

        // create our plane mesh
        var plane = webGLCurtain.addPlane(planeElement, params);
        // if our plane has been successfully created
        // we use the onRender method of our plane fired at each requestAnimationFrame call
        plane && plane.onRender(function () {
            plane.uniforms.time.value++; // update our time uniform value
        });
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        loadAnimation();
    }


</script>

<script id="plane-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
    #endif

    // those are the mandatory attributes that the lib sets
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;

    // those are mandatory uniforms that the lib sets and that contain our model view and projection matrix
    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;     
    // our texture matrix uniform (this is the lib default name, but it could be changed)
    uniform mat4 uTextureMatrix0;

    // if you want to pass your vertex and texture coords to the fragment shader
    varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

    void main() {
    vec3 vertexPosition = aVertexPosition;

    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);

    // set the varyings
    // thanks to the texture matrix we will be able to calculate accurate texture coords
    // so that our texture will always fit our plane without being distorted
    vTextureCoord = (uTextureMatrix0 * vec4(aTextureCoord, 0.0, 1.0)).xy;
    vVertexPosition = vertexPosition;
    }
</script>

<script id="plane-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
    #endif

    // get our varyings
    varying vec3 vVertexPosition;
    varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
    // the uniform we declared inside our javascript
    uniform float uTime;
    // our texture sampler (default name, to use a different name please refer to the documentation)
    uniform sampler2D uSampler0;
    void main() {
    // get our texture coords
    vec2 textureCoord = vTextureCoord;
    // displace our pixels along both axis based on our time uniform and texture UVs
    // this will create a kind of water surface effect
    // try to comment a line or change the constants to see how it changes the effect
    // reminder : textures coords are ranging from 0.0 to 1.0 on both axis
    //    const float PI = 3.141592;
    const float PI = 2.0;
    textureCoord.x += (
    sin(textureCoord.x * 10.0 + ((uTime * (PI / 3.0)) * 0.031))
    + sin(textureCoord.y * 10.0 + ((uTime * (PI / 2.489)) * 0.017))
    ) * 0.0075;
    textureCoord.y += (
    sin(textureCoord.y * 20.0 + ((uTime * (PI / 2.023)) * 0.00))
    + sin(textureCoord.x * 20.0 + ((uTime * (PI / 3.1254)) * 0.0))
    ) * 0.0125;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uSampler0, textureCoord);
    }
</script>

<script src="https://www.curtainsjs.com/build/curtains.min.js" ></script>
```