# problem with html5 canvas can Not render rectangle when I have responsive width and height of canvas

Tags: canvas

problem with html5 canvas can Not render rectangle when I have responsive width and height of canvas
exlample is show in the code.
if I delete responsive part of the code  it renders rectangle but with it rectangle is not rendered and can not understand why

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')


canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight - 100


ctx.strokeRect(50, 50, 50, 50);


// without this part of code it renders rectangle but with it rectangle is not rendered
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeWindow)

function resizeWindow() {
    canvas.width = innerWidth
    canvas.height = innerHeight - 100
}
resizeWindow()
```

Comment: [Preventing Canvas Clear when Resizing Window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5517783)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing Canvas Clear when Resizing Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517783/preventing-canvas-clear-when-resizing-window)

Comment: Yeah I get the idea why it was not working.

Comment: Setting canvas.width or height (even the same values) will reset the canvas 2D context state to its defaults. This includes the rendered content which is cleared and pixels are all set to transparent (or black if `alpha: false` when you create the 2D context)