# How to draw more than one image in html5 canvas without losing resolution using naturalwidth and height of the two images?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw two images on the same canvas, but the second image being loaded is "erasing" the first. The images are the same size and they complete each other.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvas style="width: 400px"/>
<img id="img1" src="myImage1" />
<img id="img2" src="myImage2" />
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementByID("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img1 = document.getElementByID("img1");
var img2 = document.getElementByID("img2");

img1.onload = function(){
 canvas.width = img1.naturalWidth;
 canvas.height = img1.naturalHeight;

 ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
}

img2.onload = function(){
 canvas.width = img2.naturalWidth;
 canvas.height = img2.naturalHeight;

 ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: You are drawing one on top of another. How can you see both?

Comment: the part that one has painted the other doesn't so they complete each other

Comment: That makes no sense. If you have two images, both drawn at coordinate `0,0` then _at least_ a `1x1` pixel will be covered up from the first draw with the second draw. In short: if they 'complete' each other you should align them as such using thir `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight`. Secondly, your `.width =`  and `.height =` _also_ resets the canvas and clears it. So if you reset the width and height every time, it will result in an empty buffer. In short: you should try get a better grasp of the canvas fundamentals for this one...

Comment: _"the part that one has painted the other doesn't"_ - and just to be clear, by "not painted" you mean complete alpha transparency, yes ...?

Comment: Aside from the valid points made here, is the common misunderstanding that the canvas keeps track of all the shapes that are drawn. Think of it like a real live canvas. Whenever you paint over something else, you can not just 'unpaint' your second layer to see the first one again.

Comment: please provide the images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preventing Canvas Clear when Resizing Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517783/preventing-canvas-clear-when-resizing-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the size of the canvas clears the context.

If you're sure the images align, all you have to do is make sure you only initialize once using the dimensions of whichever image loads first:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var img2 = document.getElementById("img2");

var didInit = false;
function init(img) {
  canvas.width = img.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;
  didInit = true;
}

img1.onload = function(){
 if (!didInit) init(img1);
 ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
}

img2.onload = function(){
 if (!didInit) init(img2);
 ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}

img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<img id="img1" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="black" />

<img id="img2" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="red" />
```

Alternatively, you could wait for all images to be loaded, find the largest width and height dimension, set the canvas size and only *then* draw all the images to it.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


const loadedImages = [];
const drawImagesToPage = () => {
  let maxW = 0;
  let maxH = 0;
  
  for (const img of loadedImages) {
    maxW = Math.max(maxW, img.naturalWidth);
    maxH = Math.max(maxH, img.naturalHeight);
  }
  
  canvas.width = maxW;
  canvas.height = maxH;
  
  for (const img of loadedImages) {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
}

document
  .querySelectorAll("img")
  .forEach((img, idx, all) => {
    loadedImages.push(img);
    
    if (loadedImages.length === all.length) {
      drawImagesToPage();
    }
  });
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}

img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<img id="img1" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="black" />

<img id="img2" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="red" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change height or width because canvas will be cleared

Better wait for both images to load and then set dimensions

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var img2 = document.getElementById("img2");

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

Promise.all([
  new Promise((r) => {
    img1.onload = function() {
      r(img1);
    };
  }),
  new Promise((r) => {
    img2.onload = function() {
      r(img2);
    };
  })
]).then(([img1, img2]) => {
  const width = Math.max(img1.naturalWidth, img2.naturalWidth);
  const height = Math.max(img1.naturalHeight, img2.naturalHeight);
  
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <img id="img1" src="https://i.imgur.com/hXp1nj4.png" />
  <img id="img2" src="https://i.imgur.com/2XpTBZa.png" />
</body>

</html>
```