# Canvas resize throwing off listeners x y

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

In my html I have the following to make the canvas resize to width and height percent.

```
#canvas,
#canvasCursor {
    cursor: none;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 62%;
    height: 80%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

However this seems to increase the size of the drawing and the x y listeners.
Just **[click here](http://www.taffatech.com/Paint.html)** and you will know what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1) you are setting the width of the canvas by using CSS rule. This will not work well. If you don't set a size for canvas it will default to 300 x 150 pixels no matter what you set by CSS. This means everything in it is scaled (as if it was an image of a fixed size which is what a canvas is basically). If you *do* set a size but still uses CSS, *that* size will be scaled.

You loose performance and quality, and you would need to recalculate the mouse positions as well.

You need to update the size from Javascript.

```
#canvas, #canvasCursor {
    cursor: none;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 62%; /* REMOVE */
    height: 80%;  /* REMOVE */
    z-index: 1;
}
```

2) You are not updating the canvas size from anywhere. You can update the canvas by setting its width and height properties - to set it to the size of the window you can use:

```
    window.onresize = function() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        //call redraw
   }
```

or if you want to set it to a percentage you'll need to calculate this yourself as canvas do not take a %-value.

```
    window.onresize = function() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.62; //ie. 62% of width
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.8; //ie. 80% of height

        //call redraw
   }
```

Canvas uses ONLY pixel-sizes as this element is a special case.

Why innerWidth/Height? This represent the actual viewport for the window that you see (you will see this more clearly using a mobile device).

If you just want a fixed size you can set that directly:

```
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
```

Why do you need to update (redraw everything)? Canvas only holds a snapshot of whatever is drawn to it - it does not keep a copy of it. What's on the screen is it.

When resized it is re-initialized and therefor you need to update it again. This will have little performance cost unless you have a lot of things to redraw. This will only happen if the user resizes the browser window.

Comment: It works thank you. However the listeners are not they are messed up. Any ideas as I thought they were based on my canvas width/height? http://www.taffatech.com/Paint.html

This is the code for the listeners:  mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

Comment: @StevenBarrett Ah, for the mouse coordinates, please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130395/canvas-html5-real-mouse-position/17130415#17130415

Comment: Forget it worked it out! Thanks! - for others, remember to change the size on all canvas layers not just the main one or the listeners won't be in line!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your javascript. I checked your Paint.js in the website you provided.
You used

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
canvasWidth = canvas.width,
canvasHeight = canvas.height;
```

Meanwhile, you have canvas width and height in your html set to be 800*600.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
```

Therefore, the canvas.width(height) will return whatever in the html. Then you use 800 and 600 to do your calculation instead of the canvas' real size. That's why it looks like the canvas been zoomed in a weird way.

You should use `canvas.scrollWidth` and `canvas.scrollHeight` to get  the actual width and height information. Good luck!

Comment: I have removed the width and height and set it by percentage but its no different.

Answer (score 0):

When the canvas is resized, you need to reset its width and height accordingly.  You can do this in the `onresize` event:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    canvas.width  = canvas.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;

    // repaint everything
}
```

You'll need to do it for both the drawing canvas and the cursor canvas.  Bear in mind that everything will be cleared when the canvas is resized and [you will need to repaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543358/resizing-a-html-canvas-blanks-its-contents).

Comment: Would this mean I need to save everything that is drawn on the canvas. Would this slow down a paint program?

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that when the canvas is resized it is automaticially cleaned up which means that everything painted on it is completely gone. So I'm advising you either not to choose percentage or to attach repainting function on resize event!

Comment: I would have to save every shape to an array in this case right? and this would slow everything down?