# Drawing to canvas on mouse click is off

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, drawimage, onmousedown

My `<canvas>` element takes up `100vw` and `100vh`. I want to be able to click anywhere on it and have a picture drawn there. Right now, when I click on the screen, the image does not get drawn anywhere close to where I click. The closer I click to the top left corner, the closer it is. But if I deviate from the corner even slightly, the image gets pushed really far down and to the right.

How can I calculate the offset I seem to need in order to get the image to draw exactly where I click?

```js
//var count1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.width)) + 1;
//var count2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * screen.height)) + 1;

function onCanvasClick() {
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  var xLoc = event.clientX;
  var yLoc = event.clientY;
  var loc = "xLoc is: " + xLoc + " | yLoc is: " + yLoc;
  console.log(loc);
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(image, xLoc, yLoc);
}
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  width: 99vw;
  height: 99vh;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-color: rgba(58, 154, 221, 0.3);
}

#image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" onmousedown="onCanvasClick()">You dont support this!</canvas>
<img id="image" src="//via.placeholder.com/100"></img>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resizing the canvas with CSS stretches its contents, similar to how an `<img>` behaves.
Stretching offsets the canvas coordinates relative to your mouse click.
For example, a click at coordinates (5,5) could translate to stretched canvas coordinates of (15,25).

> [**Sizing the canvas**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#Sizing_the_canvas)
> The displayed size of the canvas can be changed
> using a stylesheet. The image is scaled during rendering to fit the
> styled size. If your renderings seem distorted, try specifying your
> width and height attributes explicitly in the  attributes, and
> not using CSS.

You can set canvas dimensions via JavaScript in order to make it fill the viewport.

```js
var image = document.getElementById("image");
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;

function onCanvasClick() {
  var xLoc = event.clientX;
  var yLoc = event.clientY;
  ctx.drawImage(image, xLoc, yLoc);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#myCanvas {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(58, 154, 221, 0.3);
}

#image {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" onmousedown="onCanvasClick()" width="100%" height="100%">You dont support this!</canvas>
<img id="image" src="//via.placeholder.com/50">
```

For more reference, see:
[HTML5 Canvas distorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397315/html5-canvas-distorted)
[Resize HTML5 canvas to fit window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664785/resize-html5-canvas-to-fit-window)
[HTML5 Canvas 100% Width Height of Viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288253/html5-canvas-100-width-height-of-viewport)

---

Resizing will clear the canvas, so a responsive design will require additional functionality.
[Matthew Crumley has ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543358/resizing-a-html-canvas-blanks-its-contents#answer-3543909) for redrawing/scaling existing content when resizing.

Comment: That definitely sounds like it could work. Didn’t think that it was me stretching the canvas that would cause that. When I get back to my laptop tomorrow morning I’ll check if this works and give you that check mark if it’s does. Thanks!